# Top 1 for each joined record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

In this SQL Server query, I want to return at most 1 lostReason for each booking. However, the sub-query seems to be returning the first record from the lostBusiness table for every booking. Let me know if I need to clarify.

```
SELECT        
    bookings.bookingNumber, lost.lostReason
FROM            
    bookings 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT TOP (1) 
                       bookingNumber, 
                       lostReason
                    FROM            
                       lostBusiness) AS lost ON bookings.bookingNumber = lost.bookingNumber
```

Comment: CROSS APPLY it or use a ranking function. If it's only one attribute you need, consider a correlated subquery in your column list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you need more than one column

```
select      
    bookings.bookingNumber, lost.*
from bookings
    outer apply
    ( 
        select top 1
            lost.bookingNumber, 
            lost.lostReason,
            --other columns
        from lostBusiness as lost
        where bookings.bookingNumber = lost.bookingNumber
        order by -- put you order by here
    ) as lost
```

or

```
;with cte as (
    select      
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by bookings.bookingNumber order by /* ??? */) as row_num
    from bookings
        left outer join lostBusiness as lost on bookings.bookingNumber = lost.bookingNumber
 )
 select * from cte where row_num = 1
```

if you need more than one column

```
select      
    bookings.bookingNumber, max(lost.lostReason) as lostReason
from bookings
    left outer join lostBusiness as lost on bookings.bookingNumber = lost.bookingNumber
group by bookings.bookingNumber
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want any lost reason, `MAX` or `MIN` would do:

```
SELECT        
    Bookings.BookingNumber, 
    MAX(LostBusiness.LostReason) as SomeLostReason
FROM            
    Bookings
    LEFT JOIN LostBusiness ON bookings.BookingNumber= lostBusiness.BookingNumber
GROUP BY
    Bookings.BookingNumber
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query fails because you are joining to a single record, not to a record for each booking.

Try this

```
select *,
    (
          select top 1 
                 lostreason 
          from lostbusiness
          where lostbusiness.bookingnumber = bookings.bookingnumber
          -- order by goes here.
      )
from bookings
```

You should understand that data doesn't have any inherent order, so you should define what you mean by the "first" reason, by means of an `order by` clause in the subquery.